# Is Spark’s map and reduce operations are different to Hadoop Map Reduce, If yes then how?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop2

I was going through the spark document and found the below line

**Hadoop MapReduce and does not directly relate to Spark’s map and reduce operations**

1.Could you please help me to understand how the spark map reduce is different to the hadoop map reduce?

2. How the RDD works in spark? Is it always converting the code to mapreduce like hive?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources available on the web for illustrating the difference between Hadoop MapReduce and Spark MapReduce which you can go through but still, below I am pointing key difference so that you can get an idea :

1. Apache Spark is a framework for real-time data analytics in a
   distributed computing environment. It executes in-memory
   computations to increase the speed of data processing. It is faster
   for processing large-scale data as it exploits in-memory
   computations and other optimizations. Therefore, it requires high
   processing power. while Hadoop MapReduce has to read from and write
   to a disk. As a result, the speed of processing differs
   significantly – Spark may be up to 100 times faster. However, the
   volume of data processed also differs: Hadoop MapReduce is able to
   work with far larger data sets than Spark.

### Tasks Hadoop MapReduce is good for :

- Linear processing of huge data sets.
- Economical solution, if no immediate results are expected

### Tasks Spark is good for:

- Fast data processing
- Iterative processing
- Near real-time processing etc.

Now lets jump to your second question Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD) is a fundamental data structure of Spark. It is an immutable distributed collection of objects. Each dataset in RDD is divided into logical partitions, which may be computed on different nodes of the cluster. RDDs can contain any type of Python, Java, or Scala objects, including user-defined classes. 
So in Spark two operations are performed on RDDs (Transformations, Actions)
the logic doesnt get executed unless you perform Action operation that's why it is called lazy evalutaion

Comment: This has been answered couple of times. You can get a lot of answers and detailed explanation on stackoverflow itself. Try to search